# Include Jquery for web browser control in wpf

Tags: jquery, wpf, webbrowser-control

I am using web browser control in my project ,i can display html data easily with this control,
 now i am trying to include jquery in this html but any how it does not seems to be working

```
  WebBrowser webwsr = new WebBrowser();
  String WebBrwseHTML = "<html><head><script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.7.1.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function () {  $('div').css('background-color', 'Red'); })</script></head><body><div>DUMMY</div></body></html>";

   webwsr.NavigateToString(WebBrwseHTML);
```

what i am doing wrong here

Comment: Any updates? Could u did it?

Answer (score 1):

not a big jq expert but try this:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("<html>");
        sb.AppendLine("<head>");
        sb.AppendLine(" <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>");
        sb.AppendLine("<script>");
        sb.AppendLine("$(document).ready(function () {");
        sb.AppendLine("$('div').css('background-color', 'Red'); });");
        sb.AppendLine("</script>");
        sb.AppendLine("</head>");
        sb.AppendLine("<body>");
        sb.AppendLine("<div>DUMMY</div>");
        sb.AppendLine("</body>");
        sb.AppendLine("</html>");

        WebBrowser webwsr = new WebBrowser();
        String WebBrwseHTML = sb.ToString();
        webwsr.NavigateToString(WebBrwseHTML);
        mainGrid.Children.Add(webwsr);
```

Comment: The idea is to load LOCAL JavaScript file. (Application should work without Internet)

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to use `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(jqueryFilePath)` to read the base jQuery code, and then instead of `<script src="..."></script>` use `<script>" + jquery + "</script>`.

Below is a working example: (replace the `@"C:\jquery.txt"` with your own path)

```
var jquery = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\jquery.txt");

var html = @"<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>"+jquery+@"</script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('div').css('background-color', 'Red');
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>DUMMY</div>
</body>

</html>";

browser.NavigateToString(html);
```